# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with javascript in the address bar

Tags: javascript, browser

When I want to type  the following code to the address bar, the console yields `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. If use `var` instead of `let`s, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'`. However, running on the console works.

```
javascript:function myFun(){
let text = document.getElementsByClassName('mdui-textfield-input')[1].innerHTML.match(/(?<=src=\").*?(?=\")/g)[0]
let textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.value = text;
        textArea.style.opacity = "0"; 
        document.body.appendChild(textArea);
        textArea.focus();
        textArea.select();


        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            alert('Copying text command was ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Unable to copy value , error : ' + err.message);
        }

        document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}myFun();
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon: `")/g)[0];`

Comment: @NickParsons why do I need that one in this case?

Comment: well your code will be interpreted as `match(/(?<=src=\").*?(?=\")/g)[0]let textArea` when pasted into your browser address bar as one line, which is a syntax error due to `[0]let`, the `;` seperates the two statements

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missing ; in second line

```
let text = document.getElementsByClassName('mdui-textfield-input')[1].innerHTML.match(/(?<=src=\").*?(?=\")/g)[0]
```